# Error: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.dbtest.springboot.db_model.Family.user]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Tell me how to correctly add a collection consisting of information objects to the database (a table, for example, a family) and so that these objects refer to one user in the user table. At the moment, an error occurs, tried different save options, the error continues:

Request json:

```
[

{
"name":"luda",
"surname":"Petrova",
"phone":"2353636",
"bus":"black"
},
{
"name":"dima",
"surname":"Petrov",
"phone":"23536336",
"bus":"red"
},
{
"name":"ivan",
"surname":"Petrov",
"phone":"2353",
"bus":"blue"
}

]
```

RestController :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "fam/{id}" },method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addyfam (@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<FamReq> fammreq){
        User usr = userRepo.findById(id).get();     
                var arr = new ArrayList<Family>();
        
        for(FamReq f : fammreq ) {
    
             arr.add(new Family( f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus()));
             
        }
                
        usr.setFamily(arr);
        
        userRepo.save(usr);     
        return usr;
    }
```

Entity 1 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usr")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Passport passport;
    
    
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
    private List<Family> family = new ArrayList<>();
 
  /**get/set and constr **/


}
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="family")
public class Family {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="bus")
    private String bus;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        )
    @MapsId
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;
    
   /**get/set and constr **/
}
```

Since the primary key identifier is identical to the foreign key, it is necessary that the family table contains only the secondary key, and the user table contains only its primary key.

UPDATE :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "fam/{id}" },method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addyfam (@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<FamReq> 
 fammreq){
    User us = userRepo.findById(id).get();
    
    var arr = new ArrayList<Family>();
    
    for(FamReq f : fammreq ) {
    
    Family savedFamily = famRepo.save(new Family(f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus()));
    
       arr.add(savedFamily);
    
    Family(f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus()));
   } 
    userRepo.save(arr);
    
    return us;
   }
```

If, in essence, the family indicates this:

```
@ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY
            )
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private User user;
```

Error:

```
ERROR: NULL in column "user_id" of relationship "family" violates NOT NULL constraint
   Details: The error line contains (sdgsgsgsegf, luda, 2353636, Petrova, null, null)
```

If you indicate this:

```
@ManyToOne(
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY
            )
        @MapsId
        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        private User user;
```

then

Error:

```
Error: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.dbtest.springboot.db_model.Family.user]
```

UPDATE:

the controller is currently in use :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "fam/{id}" },method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public User addyfam (@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<FamReq> fammreq){
            User usr = userRepo.findById(id).get();     
                    var arr = new ArrayList<Family>();
            
            for(FamReq f : fammreq ) {
        
                 arr.add(new Family( f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus()));
                 
            }
                    
            usr.setFamily(arr);
            
            userRepo.save(usr);     
            return usr;
        }
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long >{
User findByname(String name);

void save(ArrayList<Family> fm);
```

}

full error :

```
Hibernate: insert into family (bus, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into family (bus, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into family (bus, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-11-14 23:31:06.693 ERROR 13192 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!
at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:58) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:46) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:596) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: please tell me, it takes a long time to solve the problem, I don't understand how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you try to make a relation by *Id* but `new Family( f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus())` does not assign any *Id* to your *Family*.

1. Create Family Object and store it into a variable.
2. Save your Family with the help of `.save(familyObject)` only then your *Family* is assigned with an *Id*.
3. Save your `User` with a *Family* attached to it.

Your controller should look like this:

```java
        for (FamReq f : fammreq ) {
             Family savedFamily = familyRepo.save(new Family(f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus(), us.getId()));
             arr.add(savedFamily);
        }
        us.setFamily(arr);wq21`
        userRepo.save(us);
```

You also should have a `FamilyRepository` like so:

```java
@Repository
public interface FamilyRepo extends JpaRepository<Family, Long>{
    
}
```

NOTE: Do not forget to create injection of this class in your Controller.

NOTE: Never override the `.save()` method in the Repositories.

Plus you have to insure that your user is found by *id* otherwise throw an exception that will be caught by [Global Controller Advice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc). Because if you do not your JPA will try to create a relation while referring to a `NULL` value.

Comment: ERROR: NULL in column "user_id" of relationship "family" violates NOT NULL constraint
   Details: The error line contains (sdgsgsgsegf, luda, 2353636, Petrova, null, null)
Add code , new controller . what could be wrong yet?

Comment: 1. You could make your User `nullable = true` but I will not suggest you doing so instead:
2. Assign the User field to your savedFamily directly when created. The error itself tell you so: "Your User is null in Family" so when it is saved it throws Error

`Family savedFamily = famRepo.save(new Family(f.getName(),f.getSurname(),f.getPhone(),f.getBus(), us.getId()));`

Comment: but can you please write an example. Since I do not quite understand at what point to save?

Comment: if you specify us.getId(), then the error is there NULL

Comment: Do you use Debug Mode? To see what is your variable at the moment?
How could it be `NULL` if you just found it by id `.findById()`?
You should just get that userId and send it to the `Family constructor`.

Comment: I highly suggest not to use this method, but for educational purposes here is how we say that this relation can be nullable:

`@JoinColumn(name = "some_name", nullable = true)`

Comment: I got this error Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!

Comment: Where did it happen? While you were calling `findById()` function?

Comment: I cleaned the database, then added a user and wanted to add information about parents for him and this error came out. Added information to the post